# Need help finding the character encoding for my name

Tags: characters, simplified-characters, traditional-vs-simplified

Chinese here! I have a really rare symbol in my name. The symbol was originally in the ‘traditional’character set, written as 頔 (pronounced as ‘di’) , but later China came up with a simplified version of this symbol(shown below, picture of the symbol from my passport). I tried the drawing recognition on windows but was unable to find it.

I am in urgent need to open a bank account but because the banks cannot type out the exact character shown on my passport they refuse to open a bank account for me. I am just wondering if the character exists in GB18030 standard so I could give the bank the encoding for this symbol.

Or does anyone know how to write this symbol on the computer? Thanks lots!!
[image: this is the symbol I need]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[頔](http://www.zdic.net/z/27/js/9814.htm) U+9814

[image: U9814.png]

U+2CC56

[image: U2cc56.png]

必需装含有“扩充-E”的字型才能显示。（请自己去找字型，noto 可能可以）GB18030 应该没有。

Comment: 谢谢！那我去试一试， 看看在我的电脑上行不行